# Perl Module not available after cpan Installation

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm running Ubuntu 14.  I tried installing Tk module via cpan.  It appears to have installed correctly, however when I tried to use Tk; in my script it still says its unavailable.  Is there anything I can do, perhaps add it to @INC somehow? thanks! 
Ahdee

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the path that the module was installed to and the full error message you get when you try to use it. Also, Perl is case-sensitive; are you really doing `use Tk;` and not `use tk;`, for example?

Answer (score 1):

It would generally be recommended to install perl modules from the packaging system. For example, in Debian/Ubuntu, Tk would be "perl-tk". Also, since the Tk module includes Tk inside of it, it can't take advantage of newer versions until it is updated to include them. You might look instead at something like [Tkx](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/Tkx-1.09/) which is libtkx-perl in Debian/Ubuntu. The upside is it uses the system Tk libraries for newer versions; the downside is you have to be more familiar with Tcl as it is a simple binding.